# Bounded Operators: Topological Dual

Tags: functional-analysis, operator-theory, hilbert-spaces

Given Hilbert spaces $\mathcal{H}$ and $\mathcal{K}$.

Consider the bounded operators:
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K}):=\{T:\mathcal{H}\to\mathcal{K}:\|T\|<\infty\}$$

Regard the linear functionals:
$$l_{(\varphi,\psi)}T:=\langle T\varphi,\psi\rangle_\mathcal{K}:\quad|l_{(\varphi,\psi)}T|\leq\|\varphi\|_\mathcal{H}\|\psi\|_\mathcal{K}\cdot\|T\|$$

Do these exhaust its topological dual:
$$\mathcal{B}(\mathcal{H},\mathcal{K})'=\overline{\langle\{l_{(\varphi,\psi)}:(\varphi,\psi)\in\mathcal{H}\times\mathcal{K}\}\rangle}$$
*(I'm wondering about this already for some time.)*

Comment: In finite dimension spaces, these are only the rank 1 matrices. So no, the dual space is larger.

Comment: @user251257: Linear functionals are always rank one. What do you mean exactly by matrices?

Comment: If this was the case, the set would be closed under addition, which it isn't. However, the **closed linear span** of them is the entire dual.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Aha ok makes sense. Can you provide a sketched proof of this fact?

Comment: Consider the annihilator. If the span of your set was not dense, there would be some $T\in\mathcal B(\mathcal H,\mathcal K)$ such that $l_{(\varphi,\psi)}T = 0$ for all $\varphi,\psi$. But this is of course only possible for $T = 0$. Note moreover that you can reduce your set to all $\varphi,\psi$ from orthonormal bases.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Ahhha great got it, thanks alot!!!

Comment: Sorry, but I doubt that my argument is correct since we are not reflexive.

Comment: @FriedrichPhilipp: Your argument is incorrect, I think. For example, consider the space $L^\infty = X$. Then $L^1 \lneq X^\ast$, but still $f =0$ if $\phi(f)=0$ for all $\phi \in L^1$ and $f\in X$.

Comment: Better argument for a certain special case. If $H,K$ are infinite dimensional and separable, then so is your "special set" of functionals. But $B(H,K)$ is not separable (I am rather certain), so that it's dual is also not separable.